# How to detect MPMoviePlayerViewController standardcontrol appear/disappear

Tags: ios, ios7, custom-controls

I want to be able to detect appear and disappear standard control of `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. I added an `UIButton` on `MPMoviePlayerViewController`, I want to show and hide this `UIButton` when `MPMoviePlayerViewController` controls appear and disappear. `touchesbegan` and `touchend` methods are not working on the `MPMoviewPlayerViewController`, and also gesture is not working on the `MPMoviewPlayerViewController`.

```
NSMutableString *videoUrl = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:VIDEO_URL];
    //[videoUrl appendString:movie.streamUrl];
    [videoUrl appendString:@"almosthuman.mp4"];
    [videoUrl appendString:@"/playlist.m3u8"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:videoUrl];

    player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    [player.moviePlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming];
    //[player.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
    [player.moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill];


    NSString *subtitlesPathStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"subtitle" ofType:@"srt"];

    [player.moviePlayer openSRTFileAtPath:subtitlesPathStr
                               completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                   // Activate subtitles
                                   [player.moviePlayer hideSubtitles];

                                   [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];

                               } failure:^(NSError *error) {

                                   NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);

                               }];

    [player.moviePlayer.view addSubview:btnLanguage];
    timerSessionTimeOut = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:7.5 target:self selector:@selector(hideBtnLanguage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: Have you got any relevant code to share. It will help you get a good answer.

Comment: I wanna show and hide "btnLanguage" as MpMoviePlayerViewController standart control